# How to force json.net to deserialize DataTable column from integer to float

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to desrialize a json into a datatable. My JSON looks like below:
[{
    "Id": 35,
    "Name": "ABC",
    "XVar": 0.078814,
    "YVar": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 79,
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "XVar": 1.50,
    "YVar": 30.2
  }]

I'm using the following code to deserialize:
var dataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, (typeof(DataTable)));

The problem is that the Y value for the second object is serialized as 30 and not 30.2. What is the simplest thing I can do to preserve the data. All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is that by default, the Json.Net `DataTableConverter` which is used to serialize and deserialize the `DataTable` type, uses the first object within the json string to detect the type of the value for each column. Since `YVar` on the first object is an integer, then it assumes all other objects will be integers as well on that column.

You have 2 options:

1. Format your values as floats even when they are int values, in this case, your json string should have "YVar": **1.0** instead of "YVar": **1**
2. Take json.net [DataTableConverter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs) source and tailor it to your needs. This would require you to use the overload of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, Type type, params JsonConverter[] converters)`