# JSon Deserialization to DataTable issue when parsing DataType

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When i try to deserialize JSon, Value of the column will be converted from float to int.

Below is Json:-

```
{{
  "ImportData": [
{ 
  "ProdName": "Pipes",
  "Qty": 11.3,
  "Rate": 610.3,
  "Discount": 20,
},
{ 
  "ProdName": "Drill Machine",
  "Qty": 12,
  "Rate": 400.3,
  "Discount": 10.3,
},
{
  "ProdName": "Cement",
  "Qty": 50,
  "Rate": 1110.5,
  "Discount": 15.5,
}
],
"TypeId": 1,
"SourceId": 1,
"CreatedBy": 35
}}
```

I have Declare the Json Serializer settings to handle floats...

```
  JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
    FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal
  };
```

and supply the settings when deserializing...

```
 dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(objParam["ImportData"].ToString(),settings);
```

### dt output:-

```
ProdName        Qty   Rate     Discount
------------------------------------------------
Pipes           11.3  610.3    20
Drill Machine   12    400.3    10
cement          50    1110.5   15
```

### expected output:-

```
ProdName        Qty     Rate    Discount
------------------------------------------------
Pipes           11.3    610.3   20
Drill Machine   12      400.3   10.3
cement          50      1110.5  15.5
```

Can anyone suggest me on how to solve this issue? I went through many posts but didn't find the working solution.

Comment: I think your issue is more likely to be caused by the first type of value in the `datatable` i.e. `20` which is of `int` type that's why the `datatable` assumes all the values in the columns are of type `int only`. Furthermore, it is also explained in here (link) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603215/2417602). So, what you can try is either change the incoming value from `20` to `20.0` or create the table manually with your desired types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Json.NET's `DataTableConverter` assigns `DataColumn.DataType` from values present in the first row only.

That is why your **Qty** and **Rate** fields are mapped correctly.

I would suggest using a strictly typed object that matches your JSON and then deserializes it into it.

You can also create your own implementation of `DataTableConverter` for the same if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have Formatted values as floats when they are numeric values using javascript.

```
if (obj.DataType == 'numeric') {
  row[obj.SourceFieldName]=row[obj.SourceFieldName].toFixed(2);
}
```

@vikscool thanks, you saved a lot of my time